# Prevent key binding on shared Javascripts

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a situation where I am working with a client page which has an existing Javascript that binds the enter key with form validation. I now have to insert a new javascript file which has auto suggestion functionality and can get input when user presses the enter key on selected suggestion. But this enter key messes up with the flow on the page and triggers form validation.

Situation is like this:

> client.js // I have no control over. This triggers form validation on
>   enter key. Script code cannot be changed
>
> myscript.js // This is auto suggestion script attached to only on input element but user can select an option by pressing enter key on selected suggestion also. I can control everything here.

I tried having `event.preventDefault()` on myscript.js where i am handling the enter key but it does not work and still triggers the form validation.

My question is: Can I prevent the form to be submit when dealing with my script only but work normally otherwise? My constraint is that I cannot use JQuery on the page. So the solution needs to be in native javascript.

A sample of what I am trying to do is here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6zdo6tz/)

Comment: i think you want keypress instead of keyup: http://jsfiddle.net/g8Lmt7a5/

Comment: @humble.rumble: i don't think you can/should remove that event, that would mess up the other functionality.

Comment: you can also use event attribs to intercept handlers: http://jsfiddle.net/59vqb1as/ (no submit and no alert)

Comment: @humble.rumble: how do you remove a handler you can't reach that was added in a $.ready by _client.js_ ?

Comment: Thanks  @dandavis for the fiddle, but in your example, it is not alerting the statement which i have. I want to do some processing when enter key is pressed, thats why i choose the alert statement in this example

Comment: @humble.rumble - can you please give me a jsfiddle example ?

Comment: the first fiddle i linked stops the submit and runs the handler. the 2nd one stops the submit and the handler. i assume to use the handler in the 2nd case as a stand-in for the handler added by client.js; you can do other actions in the event attrib on that one, though if you want to alert, you need to use a short setTimeout to complete your workload and stop the orig event from firing.  ex: http://jsfiddle.net/59vqb1as/2/